# Iterate through all loaded modules in a applciation and see if a certain function is being exported

Tags: c#

After getting the List of loaded modules in my application , I want to iterate through all of them and see if any of those modules is being exporting a certain function.

How can I check if the module is exporting a function?

Comment: What means _exporting a function_?`

Comment: Executes a function.For example: those functions which can be seen with dll export viewer.

Comment: You are using terms that only make sense when you talk about an unmanaged DLL.  Managed code simply doesn't work this way, *every* method gets "exported".

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways:

```
 Type IType = Type.Assembly.Load("YourProjectName").GetType("FunctionName");
 if (IType == null)
 {  
     Text = "Function Not Exist";
 }
 else
 {
     Text = "Function  Exist";
 }
```

Or by using Linq:

```
var isImplemented = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                         GetTypes().
                         Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (FunctionName)));
```

Or:

```
var isImplemented = false;
foreach (var t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
   if (!t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (FunctionName))) continue;
   isImplemented = true;
   break;
}
```